# Remove duplicated values from nested array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm getting stack-removing duplicated keys and assigning them to a new array.

**My array:**

```
  array     (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => name1
                    [actions] => add
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => name1
                    [actions] => remove
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => name2
                    [actions] => dosomething1
                )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [name] => name2
                    [actions] => dosomething1
                )

        )
```

**What I am trying to achieve:**

```
 array    (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => name1
                        [actions] => add
                        [actions] => remove
                    )         
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => name2
                        [actions] => dosomething1
                        [actions] => dosomething1
                    ) 

            )
```

**What i have tried:**

```
    public function array_unique_multidimensional($input)
{
    $serialized = array_map('serialize', $input);
    $unique = array_unique($serialized);
    return array_intersect_key($input, $unique);
}
```

It is incorrectly returning the same array. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two array keys with the save values (so two actions elements for a given element would not be possible)  What you can do is have a single action element with multiple values in it.

```
  $results = array();
  foreach ($array as $v){
      if (!isset($results[$v["name"]]){
           $results[$v["name"]] = array("name"=>$v["name"], "actions"=>array($v["actions"]));
      } else {
          $results[$v["name"]]["actions"][] = $v["actions"];
      }
  }
```

if you want to remove the string keys on the top level array you can then do.

```
 $results = array_values($results);
```

Comment: Works like a charm, u r a star